# Can't get my cipher lab to work

Tags: java

I need help with my chiper lab. My instructions are:

> Write a program that accepts any number of strings as command-line
>   arguments and displays those strings encrypted with the Atbash cipher.
>   You program should be as modular as possible and use good object
>   oriented programming techniques.  Your program must be thoroughly
>   documented using javadoc comments.

I have `String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";` that should encode strings so that A would return Z and B would return Y and so on. I did my cipher lab in Eclipse and it's not running. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class CaesarCipher {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CaesarCipher cc = new CaesarCipher();
  }

  public static final int ALPHASIZE = 26;
  public static final char [] alpha = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
  protected char[] encrypt = new char[ALPHASIZE];
  protected char[] decrypt = new char[ALPHASIZE];

  public CaesarCipher() {
    for (int i=0; i<ALPHASIZE; i++)
      encrypt[i] = alpha[(i + 3) % ALPHASIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<ALPHASIZE; i++)
      decrypt[encrypt[i] - 'A'] = alpha[i];
  }

  /** Encryption Method */
  public String encrypt(String secret) {
    char[] mess = secret.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<mess.length; i++)
      if (Character.isUpperCase(mess[i]))
        mess[i] = encrypt[mess[i] - 'A'];
    return new String(mess);
  }

  /** Decryption Method */
  public String decrypt(String secret) {
    char[] mess = secret.toCharArray();
    for (int i=0; i<mess.length; i++)
      if (Character.isUpperCase(mess[i]))
        mess[i] = decrypt[mess[i] - 'A'];
    return new String(mess);
  }  
 }
```

Comment: I assume case doesn't matter here?

Comment: it would help if you told us what does happen when you decide to run your program

Comment: this is what is giving me when I run in the eclipse...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 CaesarCipher cannot be resolved to a variable

 at CaesarCipher.CaesarCipher.main(CaesarCipher.java:5)

Comment: How are you running this? From Eclipse? From the command line with args?

Comment: Thegrinner, I did my lab in eclipse and then I click to run my lab and it don't give me anything in console..am I suppose to save it in html file to see results?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class CaesarCipher {

    private static final int A = (int)'A';
    private static final int Z = (int)'Z';

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : args)
            System.out.println(new Encoder(s));
    }

    private static class Encoder {
        private String encoded;
        public Encoder(String s) {
            s = s.toUpperCase();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (char c : s.toCharArray())
                sb.append((char)(A + Z - (int)c));
            encoded = sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return encoded; }
    }

}
```

Comment: How about **not** giving the entire code when it's a homework assignment (which the title itself says it is), and steering the person in the right direction instead? You've now provided an excellent education in how to copy and paste code in order to avoid learning. Nice work.

Comment: A.R.S i just tried it but it won't give me anything in console...pls explain to me am I suppose to get encryption in my console when i run my program or im just writing code?

Comment: It said in the title of the question "my cipher lab", and in the first sentence "my cipher lab", and "My instruction is" with a quoted assignment that indicates it's a class assignment. What part of that indicates anything other than homework?

Comment: @KenWhite Would you like me to delete this answer?

Comment: @A.R.S.  If you want, you can edit it to help him along and not just give the complete answer.

Comment: I think you should; whether you do or not is up to you. You can see from the comment to your question that the poster has already tried to simply copy and paste it to use with no effort to learn from your answer (which is why you shouldn't answer homework questions this way).

Answer (score 1):

all your `main` method does is calling the constructor of the class that your main method is in.

That's very confusing code, and isn't in very good form.

What you probably want to do is include most of your code in your main method.  you can use "use good object oriented programming techniques" by organizing code from there into other classes.

What I would do is something like

```
public class CaesarCipher 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
        {
            Cypher cypher = new Cypher(args[i]);
            System.Out.Println(cypher.Print());
        }
    }
}
```

and then in another file(or the same file is fine too)

```
public class Cypher
{
    // fields to represent your cypher

    public Cypher(String s)
    {
        //load the input string into your cypher here.  
    }

    public String Print()
    {
        //print the encrypted string
    }
}
```

you may chose to encrypt either in the constructor, the print method, or some other way.

Comment: ok Sam let me try to code my lab and I'll see what will it give me

Comment: +1. This is a better way to answer this type of question. Nice job. :-)